# What file/database stores the SMSC setting?

Tags: android, android-8.1-oreo

One of the reasons I've chosen to use Android many years ago is the ability to do anything I want to the phone.

The reason why I'm asking this question now is due to the fact that Android One Oreo 8.1 on Mi A1 is unable to send SMS. Prior to the June and July update, I'm able to send SMS on Mi A1. Now, I'm able to receive SMS, but unable to send it. The Mi A1 has 2 SIM slots, and I'm using the SIM2 slot. There's no options in the Oreo 8.1 ROM to change or set the SMSC.

*In which database/file is the SMSC setting located?* I intend to root Android, then modify the  database/file, as both Google and Xiaomi is unable to fix this issue, and I can't update the SMSC setting in `#*#*4636#*#*`, as I'm getting both update and refresh error.

Comment: "_In which database/file is the SMSC setting located?_" – AFAIK, it's not stored in a database/file. It's on the SIM card(s).

Comment: So when setting the SMSC in certain phones, this got set in the SIM card? And when the phone boots up, this got read from the SIM too?

Comment: When I move my SIM card to another phone, I was able to receive and send SMS though.

Comment: "So when setting the SMSC in certain phones..." – Yep, that's basically what I gather. "When I move my SIM card to another phone, I was able to write and send SMS though." – I'm not sure why you might expect that to not work.

Comment: It's not working on Mi A1. It's able to receive but not send SMS for the stock Android SMS app. I'm expecting it to work but it's not.

Comment: Oh, that's what you meant. I misunderstood your point. In any case, I'm not at all familiar with Mi A1. I was just addressing the database/file question.

Comment: I have this problem too. Have anybody some new informations?

Comment: Same story on a rooted Redmi 4x running on a Pie ROM, no luck with either the settings page available by typing #*#*4636#*#*, or e.g. "Advanced Signal Status" app. 
SMSC are stored on the SIM and could only be changed on another phone. Use a feature phone (no smartphone). In my case there where 3 SMSC numbers stored on the SIM; after updating the ROM, the first one was used which by chance was invalid; removed it on another phone - done.

Comment: For the Xiaomi Redmi 4X and a Android Pie ROM the solution is to enter the SMSC number on the `*#*#4636#*#*` page in the form `"+491722270333",145` (including quotes! example for german Vodafone SMSC).
It seems at least on some other phones the SMSC number entered has to be encoded, according to this [XDA thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=10854851&postcount=4).